# Текущее количество запросов в секунду mySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Необходимо получить значение (для дальнейшей программной обработки) - количество запросов в секунду, которые обрабатывает mySQL в текущий момент (а не с момента запуска СУБД).

Нужно получить то значение, которое отображает утилита mytop (см. картинку).

Подойдет SQL запрос к самой СУБД, либо способ вытащить это значение через сторонние утилиты командной строки Ubuntu.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *количество запросов в секунду, которые обрабатывает mySQL в текущий момент* Ну вообще-то весьма неоднозначный параметр, допускающий множественное толкование. Вот программа выполнила один запрос. Этот запрос для каждой итоговой записи обращается к пользовательской функции. Она выполняет два запроса, в том числе один из них модифицирующий. Который приводит к срабатыванию триггера, выполняющего два запроса... вот что считать "количеством запросов"?

Comment: для меня достаточно получить то значение, которое выдает mytop.

Comment: А кто ж знает, что он выдаёт... попробуй порыться в PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA.